# Auto restart ssh session after sleep

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, suspend, hibernate

I have an active ssh session to a remote server that it would be nice to be able to restart upon waking from sleep/hibernate (ubuntu), and seamlessly restore tunnels.

The Gnome Terminal window is still open upon restart, but it is frozen, and the programs that rely on these tunnels also hang.

I have to close and reopen the ssh connection and then shut down and restart the dependent programs.

Anyone got any nice methods of working around this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) to achieve automatic re-initiation of ssh connections, though I'd love it if someone knew a solution that is built into ssh itself.